# Looping user based filters to pull out products MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, web

Currently, i have a system set that displays products from a database based on what filters are set in a control panel.

It loops like this:

```
1. Begin loop
2. Pick Filter
3. Search product database for product matching the filter AND search term
4. Return a table row of products matching these terms
5. End Loop
```

This works fine except for the load times. Because it has to loop through all the products for each filter with search term the time involved only gets higher with each filter added on the back end.

My question: Is there a smaller way to write in say.. any array of the filters into one mysql statement? like this:

```
SELECT FROM products Where A line matches one of the array of filters AND search term?
```

The other reason i need this is because currently it's pullin gout duplicate product rows. While i've nastily hidden the doubles with javascript, it's not exactly good to keep it like this.

Currently, this is the code being used. If anyone can offer any suggestions as to how the best way to do this is, i'm all ears.

```
//connect and fetch all entries from the filter table

$filterproducts = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_filter_selection ORDER BY filter ASC");
$filterproducts->execute();
$filterselect = $filterproducts->fetchAll();
//for each entry found loop through a second loop

foreach($filterselect as $rows){
$wildcard = "%" . $rows['filter'] . "%";
//make a variable into a regex of the row   

$query = "PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%", $breakdown) . "%'";
$sqlstring= "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE PRODUCT_NAME  LIKE :filterfind AND " . $query;
$searchproducts = $dbh->prepare($sqlstring);
$searchproducts->bindParam(":filterfind", $wildcard, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$searchproducts->execute();

//search for all products that match the wildcard AND the current filter

foreach($searchproducts as $rows2){

//for every one found, make a row.
echo "<tr><td>" . $rows2['SKU'] ." <strong style='font-style: italic;'>". $rows2['COMMENTS'] . "</strong><td/><td>". $rows2['PRODUCT_NAME'] ."</td><td>". $rows2['QTY'] . "</td></tr>";
   }
}
```

I have editted to include a very quick mock-up of the code I'm using.

Comment: Well, you might want to start by showing us what your code actually looks like. It's kinda hard to say it there is a better way to do something, otherwise.

Comment: You could try "where in":   select * from table  where id in (1,2,3,4);

Comment: I've added the code as asked. I didn't have time to earlier as i was in a rush.Apologies for that @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

save the filters in an array. then use a loop to make a sql stament. like this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM products ";
$filters= 'Where '; //Sets a varible for fileters.
foreach($filters as $key=$value) //Loop threw each filter
{
    $filters.= $key . '= ' . $value . 'AND ';
}
rtrim('AND '); //Remove extra 'AND' from end of filters string
$query.= $filters;
```

Now you will have to adjust the code depending on how your filters a stored. and the rtrim() may need tweeking.